# batch send arguments to exe file C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I was doing a "script" in Batch, and I needed to send arguments to my console program made in C#, I tried YouTube tutorials and Google searches but they couldn't help me, I used this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string argument = args[1];

    Console.WriteLine("Passed argument:: " + argument);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I run this one it returns the error:

`System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The standard mechanisms are:

1. [The Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)
2. [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0)
3. [Standard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters via the commandline as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line):

```
using System;

class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the number of command line arguments.
        Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to set [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0) and use their values within the program:

```
public static string? GetEnvironmentVariable (string variable);
```